# Segmentation fault in atoi command

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int value,direction=0;
    char c;
    printf ("go\n");
    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "wr:")) != -1) {
        printf ("go\n");
        printf("%c\n",c);
        switch(c) {
        case 'w':
            printf ("go\n");
            value=atoi(optarg);
            printf ("go\n");
            printf("The input value is %x",value);
            direction=1; //1 for write
            break;
        case 'r':
            direction=0; // 0 for read
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid option: %c\n", (char)c);
            usage();
            return -1;
        }

    }
}
```

Now when i run the program by writing

```
 ./spicode.out -w 25
```

I need to pick the 25 after w using optarg, but its producing a segmentation fault.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: But you say that the `-w` option *doesn't* take any argument. Only the `-r` option does. Did you by mistake place the colon wrongly?

Comment: I don't understand where i did that..

Comment: With `"wr:"`. The colon in that string tells `getopt` that the previous option character (`r` in your case) have an argument that will be put in `optarg`. Because `-w` doesn't take an option the pointer `optarg` will be undefined and can't be used. If `-w` takes an argument but not `-r` then you should use `"w:r"`. Perhaps you should read a bit more about [`getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html)?

Comment: Oh, this must be what i am doing wrong! Thank you so much for your help! It solved my problem.

Comment: Also a note about terminology: [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) is not a "command" but a *function*. C doesn't have commands, it has statements and expressions, and some expressions are function calls, like e.g. `atoi(optarg)` which is a call to the [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) function passing `optarg` as argument.

Comment: Can you also please explain what the function atoi(optarg) does? What exactly is optarg? Also you should post your answer in the answers for me to mark it?

Comment: I have provided links to references for both [`getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) and [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi). Please read them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150784/discussion-between-mobi-zaman-and-some-programmer-dude).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put colon between commandline options.

```
   c = getopt(argc, argv, "w:r")
```

Answer (score 2):

From gnu.org :

> An option character in this string can be followed by a colon (‘:’) to
>   indicate that it takes a required argument

Therefore `wr:` becomes `w:r`